# Intel VTune Profiler shows __mulq is a computationally expensive function in a fortran code

Tags: fortran, openmp, intel-vtune

I'm trying to perform an audit on a rather complicated multi-physics model I'm working on and have been using Intel VTune Profiler to identify expensive subroutines. The most expensive function is a function called __mulq which is not something within the source code. I can see which subroutines are calling it, but I cannot figure out what exactly it is. I'm using the Intel fortran compiler. I have also tried using grep to search for __mulq within the directory containing all the code, and the only mentions of __mulq are within binary files. Can someone identify what this __mulq function may be? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @francescalus I'm unsure. How would I be able to check? I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.2

Comment: The CPU is an intel i9, architecture is x86_64 with 32-bit and 64-bit modes.

Comment: If you're using 128-bit reals then I'd assume that the `__mulq` is part of the compiler runtime taking care of parts of the arithmetic using them. (Maybe someone more familiar with this low level bits can explain further.)

Comment: I'm using double precision which is 64-bit in Fortran 90. Are you suggesting reducing to single precision?

Comment: I'm not suggesting any changes to your code, just where `__mulq` comes from. (As a general case, if a symbol name starts with `__` it's not created by user code.)

Comment: Right, I should have mentioned that I am trying to reduce the amount of wall-time __mulq is incurring

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If there is `__mulq`, there is a float multiply on 16-byte floats, i.e. Fortran "quad" precision, that requires additional support routines as that precision is not offered by x86 instructions. Hence, your code is not using only 32- and 64-bit floats.

Answer (score 0):

By using the Bottom up pane in vtune you would be able to figure out the call stack, and traversing through source code and assembly, get to know which library or module makes use of the mulq function

From x86 guides it could be seen mulq instructions store the result of multiplying two 64-bit values—the first as given by the source operand, and the second from register %rax. As mulq instructions are low level in the assembly and these might be from a library or any module you are using in code. If you are able to figure out the function/module which makes use of mulq function, you could try making changes to the module to either use a diff implementation or reduce calls which reslut in mulq instruction. FOr eg if this is a third party library you could look for optimised alternatives.

Comment: The __mulq function is a compiler support routine of Intel Fortran, that computes a 128-bit **float** multiplication. It's *not* the same as the mulq cpu instruction, that multiplies 64-bit integers.